# How to build live video streaming application from scratch for app and web both i want full details of requirements like streaming server?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, http-live-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

How to build real time video streaming application what software requirement i need like streamlining server or other software.
     How can i send join request to my friends and show my live video to joined users like facebook live streaming module.

Answer (score 0):

You need a media server, in your case, RTMP media server will do the job and there are a lot of open source-based projects that you can use instead of building your own media server. You can read more about RTMP [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol).